# How to reorder divs / alter markup at breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have two divs displayed inline-block beside each other, each with 45% width. At a certain break-point their widths are both changed to 100%, causing them to stack. This is obviously super simple. My question is this: how can I alter the markup at said break-point to cause what would be the bottom div to appear on top?

My existing markup relies heavily on `inline-block` level display, and I'd prefer to not switch things over to `flexbox` site-wide at this time. Thus, I am after a solution which uses `inline-block`.

Consider this simple example:

```css
.left, .right {
  display:inline-block;
  width:45%;
  text-align:center;
}
.left {
  background-color:tomato;
}
.right {
  background-color:aquamarine ;
}
p {
  padding:50px 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
 .left, .right {
    width:100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <p>LEFT</p>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <p>RIGHT</p>
</div>
```

Everything works great here, but my desired result is that the **RIGHT** `div` appears on top of the **LEFT** `div` after the break-point. I can obviously achieve this using `flexbox` to reorder the divs, but that would require hours and hours of work to switch everything over to support this display property. I need an `inline-block` solution. Thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` css property. The basic approach would be to set the parent element (e.g., container) to `display: flex;` this generates the flexbox and allows you to set different parameters for the children like

```
  .right{
    order: 1;
  }
  .left{
    order: 2
  }
```

Depending on what browsers you need to support your website, you could use the `flex-box`. check the flex box support [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```css
.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.right {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

p {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .left,
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    flex-direction: column
  }
  .right {
    order: 1;
  }
  .left {
    order: 2
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="left">
    <p>LEFT</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <p>RIGHT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

You can use `rotate()` transform functions to get your desired result. Working demo below:

```css
.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.right {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

p {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .left,
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  .container>div {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="left">
    <p>LEFT</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <p>RIGHT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update 2** *Using jQuery*

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 550) {
    $('.left').remove().insertAfter($('.right'));
  } else {
    $('.left').remove().insertBefore($('.right'));
  }
})
```

```css
.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.right {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

p {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .left,
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class="left">
    <p>LEFT</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <p>RIGHT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Again, plus 1 because this works, but if possible I'd like a solution that sticks with `inline-block`.

Comment: @Claire I have updated the answer with your requirements. Have a look

Comment: This is pretty hacky. I probably won't use this, but props on thinking outside the box like that. Pretty good idea.

Comment: Apart from `flexbox` solution (which I have provided), rest everything will be hacky in one way or the another. `inline-block` can not change the order by itself

Comment: I'm learning that more as I conduct research here. I was hoping a javascript solution would pop up that would let me prepend my div at the breakpoint or something. it might end up being flexbox..

Comment: With JS comes great caution, you might end up writing more lines of codes than what can be just achieved by flexbox. But I agree, it all depends on how you want to code. Cheers!

Comment: I agree, however in this case there are hundreds of divs relying on inline-block styling and switching everything over just to support a small feature would take several hours, whereas a js solution might take 10-15 minutes. thanks though!

Comment: @Claire I have updated using Jquery. But use it wisely if you really have 100's of divs :)

Comment: That's the one. I wish I could give you plus 3 for this. You provided 3 working solutions. Thank you very much. Yes, much easier for me to just drop this in to my js and then add classes to the divs i want to reorder at the breakpoints. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use float to specify the placement of the div, then switch the divs on your html so that the right is above of the left

```css
.left, .right {
  display:inline-block;
  width:45%;
  text-align:center;
}
.left {
  background-color:tomato;
  float:left;
}
.right {
  background-color:aquamarine ;
  float:right;
}
p {
  padding:50px 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
 .left, .right {
    width:100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <p>RIGHT</p>
</div>

<div class="left">
  <p>LEFT</p>
</div>
```

Comment: plus 1 because this works, but I should have mentioned I do not want to use `float` or `table` properties. I'd prefer to do this using `inline-block` display unless their is a more modern way. `float` is too old..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you can use display `flex` since they provide a lot of benefits in aligning, positioning etc.

I've created a solution for your problem, By wrapping the `.left` and `.right` inside a flex container, and changing the flex-direction accordingly.

```
.container
{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:flex-start
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) { 
   .container
  {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column-reverse;
    justify-content:flex-start
  }
}
```

I've created a working fiddle for better understanding: https://jsfiddle.net/Baliga/pqo69s3t/2/

Comment: Yes i understand the benefits of `flexbox`. As stated in the question, I have existing markup which relies heavily on `inline-block`, and I need a solution which does not require a change to the display property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution without using `flex`, they the only way you can achieve by using css is by making the div `absolute` positioning, but the `height` and `top`|`bottom` value has to be defined accordingly.

Otherwise, Using javascript is the only way to do it. Example:

```
leftDiv = document.getElementById( 'left' );
rightDiv = document.getElementById( 'right' );
fd.parentNode.removeChild( leftDiv );
sd.parentNode.insertAfter( leftDiv, rightDiv );
```

You can trigger this at a particular viewport width and get your div's order switch.